# Como desativar "tela cheia" do html5 video em qualquer navegador?

Tags: html5-video

Como posso desativar tela cheia em qualquer navegador ?

Segue a imagem onde tem círculo vermelho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os controles CSS são esses: Enjoy :)

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    display: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display{}
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {}
```

```html
<video width="400" height="260" controls="">
    <source src="http://cdn.papercut.com/video/home/home2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para isso teria que usar javascript também junto com HTML5, exatamente como colocarei abaixo ira dar certo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Teste Video</title>
</head>
<body>


<div style="text-align:center">
    <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
    <br><br>
    <video id="video1" width="420">
        <source src="p360-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<script>
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

    function playPause() {
        if (myVideo.paused)
            myVideo.play();
        else
            myVideo.pause();
    }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WPfan, agradeço a sua resposta. Eu não quero perder atributo de controles do html5 video. Eu apenas quero ocultar ou desativar a `tela cheia`.

Comment: Existem eventos onclick para fazer cada um dos atributos do vídeo, no seu lugar eu usaria dessa forma deixando de fora apenas a opção fullscreen.